# Swift custom assignment to tuple

Tags: swift, tuples, assignment-operator

I have a struct to contain a raw value and a die roll

```
var diceRoll: Int {
  Int.random(in: 1...6)
}

struct Score {
  var raw: Int
  let roll: Int
  
  init(_  raw: Int) {
    self.raw = raw
    self.roll = diceRoll
  }
  
  init(raw: Int, roll: Int) {
    self.roll = roll
    self.raw = raw
  }
}
```

and two players, so keep the values in a tuple

```
var (myScore, hisScore) = (Score(4), Score(3))
```

When I need to add or subtract modifiers to the players' scores, I use a tuple of (Int, Int)

```
(1, -1)
```

and modify the Scores with a custom operator

```
func +(lhs: (Score, Score), rhs: (Int, Int)) -> (Score, Score) {
  (Score(raw: lhs.0.raw + rhs.0, roll: lhs.0.roll), Score(raw: lhs.1.raw + rhs.1, roll: lhs.1.roll))
}
```

Instead of using an addition and an assignment to modify the Scores like this:

```
(myScore, hisScore) = (myScore, hisScore) + (1, -1)
```

I thought I could use this assignment operator

```
func +=(lhs: inout (Score, Score), rhs: (Int, Int)) {
  lhs = lhs + rhs
}
```

But

```
(myScore, hisScore) += (1, -1)
```

gives this error:

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '(Score, Score)' and '(Int, Int)'

I assume that it has to do with the way Tuples are assigned, but does anyone know what the problem is, and if it can be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

`(myScore, hisScore) += (1, -1)` doesn't work because `(myScore, hisScore)` is not a mutable thing. This is like saying

```
(1, 2, 3) += (4, 5, 6)
```

`myScore` and `hisScore` themselves are mutable, but pattern matching only works on the left hand side of `=`, not `+=`.

If you instead put the tuple into a single variable:

```
var scores = (Score(4), Score(3))
```

Then you can do:

```
scores += (1, 2)
```

To make it possible to access the scores with `myScore` and `theirScore`, you can add parameter labels to the tuple:

```
typealias Scores = (myScore: Score, theirScore: Score)
var scores: Scores = (Score(4), Score(3))

// you would also need to change the parameter type:
func +=(lhs: inout Scores, rhs: (Int, Int)) {
    lhs = lhs + rhs
}
```

Also consider changing this to a `struct` if you are not going to be pattern matching on the tuple much.